# Difference between conv2d and conv2dtranspose with kernel size 1

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I understand that conv2d is used for downsampling and conv2dtranspose is the opposite (upsampling). However, assuming we are not using stride or padding here. Is there a difference between the two?

Downsampling means reducing the size of input dimension. for example If you have an input of (Batch Size = 5, Channel = 3, Height = 8, Width = 8), if you reduce the height and width using maxpooling (stride=2 kernel_size=2) the output becomes (Batch Size = 5, Channel = 3, Height = 4, Width = 4). That's downsampling, the opposite is upsampling (Increasing the Height and Width dimension)

for example:

```
classifier1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=10, out_channels=5, kernel_size=1)
classifier2 = torch.nn.Conv2dTranspose(in_channels=10, out_channels=5, kernel_size=1)
```

Comment: Hi ! What do you mean "is used for downsampling" ?

Comment: Downsampling means reducing the size of input dimension. for example If you have an input of (Batch Size = 5, Channel = 3, Height = 8, Width = 8), if you reduce the height and width using maxpooling (stride=2 kernel_size=2) the output becomes   (Batch Size = 5, Channel = 3, Height = 4, Width = 4). That's downsampling, the opposite is upsampling (Increasing the Height and Width dimension)

Comment: Yes, right, but I was wondering about you saying that convolution is used for downsampling, as it is in fact rarely (even more so in the example you gave with a stride of 1 so you only downsample by kerel_size//2 pixels so not much ... )

Comment: That's just an example to make it easy to compare I could add stride=2 to both but it doesnt add any more info to my original question. Please see this link if you wanna see more about strided conv vs pooling. I think both pooling and strided conv has it's own + and -. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387482/pooling-vs-stride-for-downsampling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operation wise, no difference. `ConvTranspose2d()` inserts `stride - 1` zeros inbetween all rows and columns, adds `kernel size - padding - 1` padding zeros, then does exactly the same stuff as `Conv2d()`. Default arguments result in no changes.

Though, if you actually run them back to back like this on the same input, the results will vary unless you explicitly equalize the inital weights, of course.